# Boostrap 4 navbar not displaying correctly in chrome

Tags: asp.net-core, bootstrap-4, razor-pages

I'm not seeing the navbar displayed correctly in chrome (using bootstrap 4.1.3).
Tiny hamburger icon and the home about contact are all bunched next to one another

Code shows o.k in firefox.

How can we get it t show correctly in chrome

[image]

html snippet below net core razor page using bootstrap.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" 
      data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" 
      aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/MULTIPLES/Index">
                    Home
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/About">
                    About
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Contact">
                    Contact
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Thanks

Comment: Your code runs OK in Chrome: https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/tsn5p9om/1/. Double check how you load bootstrap files in your application.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I also tested it locally in Chrome and it looks fine. Do you have any extensions or other add-ons to your Chrome install that modify the page?

Comment: From Rahul Patel: *please you attach the bootstrap.min.css link in the html head.*

Comment: Thanks for all replies.  When try and paste boostrap.min,css get an error - too many characters.  no other extensions aware off.

Comment: launched via  <environment>
        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </environment>

Comment: for some reason looks o.k on chrome when on own machine localhost but if use browser on localhost but referring to same published code on server chrome appears with the the tiny box

Answer (score 0):

Check the Console tab in the developer tools of chrome. There might be 404 errors when it is trying to access the static files

Comment: Thanks for suggestion - will try check when server back online.